# Arcpy Error 010423 when using Zonal Statistics to Table in a tool

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, spatial-analyst, zonal-statistics, error-010423

I want to include Zonal Statistics to Table to my tool. But if I do I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\test.py", line 16, in <module>
    outZSaT = ZonalStatisticsAsTable(inshape, "field_id", ndvi, outTable, "DATA", "MEAN")
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 5836, in ZonalStatisticsAsTable
    statistics_type)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Utils.py", line 47, in swapper
    result = wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 5828, in wrapper
    statistics_type)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 498, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
ExecuteError: ERROR 010423: C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Temp\arc5F5D\t_t646 does not have valid statistics as required by the operation.
Failed to execute (ZonalStatisticsAsTable).


Failed to execute (test).
Failed at Tue Nov 07 08:31:06 2017 (Elapsed Time: 0.00 seconds)
```

Here is the code:

```
import os
import os.path
import sys
import datetime
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *


inshape = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
ndvi = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
out_location = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)


outTable = out_location + "\\outtable"
outZSaT = ZonalStatisticsAsTable(inshape, "field_id", ndvi, outTable, "DATA", "MEAN")
```

inshape: Feature layer, ndvi: Raster layer and out_location: Folder

If I replace the `arcpy.GetParameterAsText` with the actual path to the files and location and run in the python window it works fine. So where that t_t646 comes from?

Answer (score 1):

If you define your tool parameters as layers (feature and raster layers) the tool will not accept a path to a feature class or raster since they're not layers. Feature/raster layers and table views are in-memory representations of your data. Feature layers might be accepted for a parameter of type 'feature class', but the opposite is not true.

So, change the data type of your first 2 parameters: use `Feature Class` for `in_shape` and `Raster Dataset` for `ndvi`.